# How to create a trigger which fires only when a number is inserted?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, insert, numbers

I want to have something like this but I do not know want is the exact code for doing the checking:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t
AFTER INSERT ON record
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN new.value is number
BEGIN
....
END;
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: This line is not working, I do not know the correct syntax. WHEN new.value is number

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error message a secret.